# Inner loop for calculation and outer loop for saving results in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I would like to create a routine that saves results for ODE integration after certain amount of iterations. That it, the routine will receive variables for `start` time, `finish` time, `step` variable size and `dt`. `dt` is the variable for the time steps in the inner loop, and `step` is the time step for the outer loop - after each `step` time I would like to save the results, and to do so between `start` and `finish`. I used this routine, but something looks wrong - sometimes it shows that it saves the results after one `step` size, sometimes after `step + dt`:

```
import numpy as np

start = 0
finish = 10
step = 1
dt = 0.1
time_elapsed = start
for tout in np.arange(start+step,finish+step,step):
    while time_elapsed < tout:
        time_elapsed+=dt
        print "time step ", time_elapsed
    print "Outer_loop time ", time_elapsed
```

Can someone spot the bug? Also, any smart idea how can I do it using only for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the iteration over the step, check out the range for example below:

```
for i in xrange(start, finish):
    #do generic code
    if i % step: #check if the iteration is a step
         #do the step code you need
```

Comment: You've missed out using `dt` in your xrange function call to specify how many steps you want to do, but otherwise this is the easiest way to achieve it.